# Print last page of a chart with Y-labels

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart that grows each day and currently it's spanning A-BC columns.
If I want to print the last page I don't get the Y-axis labels with the print.

How can I print a the last page and include the Y-axis labels so that the chart looks "complete"?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure the A-column has the Y-axis labels and nothing more. Resize the column so that it only have the labels and not the start of the chart.

Then we use VBA by copying the A-column and paste it as an image and move it to the print area, print the sheet and remove the image.

```
Sub print_last_page()
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'copy Y-axis lables, paste as image in B1 and rename the object to "Ylabels"
    ws.Range("A1:A72").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "Ylabels"
    
    
    ' this finds the last column the the chart named "Buffertpallplatser %" occupies
    x = ws.Shapes("Buffertpallplatser %").Width
    y = 0
    With ws.Shapes.AddLine(x, y, x, y)
        .TopLeftCell.Select
        .Delete
    End With
    endcol = Selection.Column ' save this column for later use


    ' do the same thing again but roll back 750 pixels.
    ' 750 pixels is about what fits the paper with the given heights of my charts, change to suit you needs
    x = ws.Shapes("Buffertpallplatser %").Width - 750
    y = 0
    With ws.Shapes.AddLine(x, y, x, y)
        .TopLeftCell.Select
        .Delete
    End With
    posleft = Selection.Left ' save this column also for later use.
    ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Ylabels")).Left = posleft ' move the image to the left most position of our print area
    ActiveCell.Select ' select the cell again
    
    ' resize the selection to the chart area, in my case 73 rows and the 750 pixels width in columns
    Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 73, endcol - Selection.Column + 1).Select
    

    ' Below is a recorded macro to print the selection and scale to fit the columns
    ' I advice you to record something that suits your case.
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ws.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ws.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    
    ' remove the image from the sheet again.
    ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Ylabels")).Delete
End Sub
```

If we step through the code it will generate this:
[image]

And the end result on paper will look like this:
[image]